# Not able to list images whose title attribute is missing in selenium

Tags: image, selenium, testing, automation, title

Below is my code i am trying to get src of image whose title attribute is missing but its not working. With below code all images are displayed but its not searching for image without title

```
public void checkimagetitle() {

    suites.setupEnviroment();
    WebDriver driver = suites.getWebDriver();
    driver.get(suites.WEB_PATH);
    Dimension d = new Dimension(1455, 900);
    driver.manage().window().setSize(d);

    try {
        List<WebElement> listImages = driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));

        System.out.println("No. of Images: " + listImages.size());

        int counter = 0;
        for (WebElement image : listImages) {
            boolean title = image.getAttribute("title") != null;

            if (title = false) {
                counter++;
                System.out.println(image.getAttribute("src"));
            } else {
                System.out.println("failed");

            }
        }
        System.out.println("No. of total images without title: " + counter);

        Logger.getLogger("results").log(new LogRecord(Level.INFO,
                MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass().getCanonicalName() != null ? "success" : "failure"));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.getLogger("results").log(new LogRecord(Level.INFO,
                MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass().getCanonicalName() == null ? "success" : "failure"));
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    driver.close();

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you get any error messages or Only that its not matching the image count you see manually?

Comment: No i am not getting any error message its only not showing correct images in fact its printing all image source on that page

Comment: Can you post sample HTML code for the page you are trying to extract? It'd be much easier to identify the problem.

Comment: It might be that an image with `title=""` in its source is returning an empty string for `boolean title = image.getAttribute("title") != null;` and therefore your condition is true. Maybe check that the title attribute is not null *and* not "empty" (e.g. an empty string: `""`)?

Comment: Actually here the case is title attribute is missing its not null not empty. The attribute itself is missing and i have to found those images

Comment: @NaveenChandar please check the below website m working on this
https://www.smartinfologiks.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a simpler solution. Rather than looping through all the images, you can directly detect img elements without title attribute by using XPATH like

```
//img[not(@title)]
List<WebElement> listImageswithoutTitle = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//img[not(@title)]"));
```

Comment: Awesome! it worked very well for me. Thank you so much. But i didn't understand how you generated this xpath?

Comment: There are lot more combinations. You can learn at https://devhints.io/xpath